# Supabase Policy Using auth.jwt() Helper

Tags: supabase

The Supabase Policy docs show the auth.jwt() helper is available. In the examples, they show retrieving the email (auth.jwt() ->> 'email' [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#verifying-email-domains)). Is it possible to access the app or user metadata properties from auth.jwt() ? If so, what's the syntax for accessing child properties?

I've tried dot notation without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the meta data like this. This is the syntax for [accessing json values in postgres](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-query-a-json-column-in-postgresql).

```sql
auth.jwt() -> 'user_metadata' ->> 'my_property'
```